# Erro ao se conectar no cassandra em Debian localhost

Tags: banco-de-dados, nosql, cassandra

Criei uma maquina virtual e instalei o Debian.
Após instalei o cassandra e verifiquei o **status** para saber que o banco esta em execução.
porem ao executar o comando `cqlsh` em localhost recebo a seguinte mensagem:
`Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})` 
Procurando na internet, falaram para usar `cqlsh 127.0.01`, `cqlsh 127.0.01:9042`, `cqlsh <hostname>` e outras variações e não obtive exito.
A unica alteração que fiz no arquivo `cassandra.yaml` foi substituir `localhost` para `127.0.0.1` nessas duas configurações 
`rpc_adrress: 127.0.0.1`
`listen_address: 127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A instalação do cassandra já vem pronta para rodar localhost. Acredito que não seja necessário nenhuma alteração no cassandra.yaml

Primeiro sugiro você verificar se o cassandra de fato está "up and running" executando o comando nodetool status. Caso o comando falha, sugiro você verificar se o cassandra de fato subiu. Você pode verificar isso executando o comando netstat -tulpn | grep 9042. Caso não tenha nenhum processo executando, seu cassandra não subiu. Sugiro avaliar os logs que normalmente ficam no /var/log do linux

Comment: era esse caminho mesmo @CoutinhoBR, estava utilizando a versão padrão do Java, e o cassandra precisa ser a versão 8